# How to watch for prop changes when data masks prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch, vue-props

So, I know that I can watch for data change in Vue by using a watcher like so:

```js
data() { return { p: 0 } },
watch: { p() {} }
```

I can also use watcher to watch props change like so:

```js
props: ['p'],
watch: { p() {} }
```

But what if I have **both** prop and data with the same name?
Like so:

```js
data() { return { p: 0 } },
props: ['p'],
watch: { p() {} }
```

In code I can use `this.p` and `this.$data.p` to distinguish them.
How can I distinguish them in a watcher?

I tried `watch: { $data.p() {} }` but this does not work.
`watch: { p() {} }` works, but is triggered by both prop change and data change.

So, how to run watcher only for a prop change and how to run a watcher only for a data change?

Comment: I would not give them the same name. I'm pretty sure ESLint advises this to do. Then you can set two watchers and write a logic for each. Also, it is advised to not alter props directly but rather copy them into a data variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a same key in `data`/`props`/`computed`/whatever , keys *must* be different as they are intended to be assigned to the single `this` object

---

You may use Composition API `watch` in `onMounted` or `setup` or whatever hook:

```
import { watch } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  data: () => ({ p: 123 }),
  props: ['p'],
  onMounted() {
    watch(() => this.$data.p, (v) => { console.log(v) })
  }
})
```

---

I'm not sure what the other object is named, maybe `this.$setup`, but you can use `setup` instead of `data`

```
import { watch, ref } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  setup: () => {
    const p = ref(123);
    watch(p, (v) => console.log(v));
    return { p }
  },
  props: ['p'],
})
```

Setup hook is recommended to use instead of mixins as it allows to rename things easily

Answer (score 0):

Since noone answered in two weeks I will write my answer I came up with:

It is possible to specify what type of property a watcher should watch (either prop or data) if both prop and data have the same name by providing the full name of the property as seen in the Vue component, as string.

So, to watch for a prop change, you would write:

```js
watch: { "_props.p"() {} }
```

and to watch data you would write:

```js
watch: { "_data.p"() {} }
```